# What is the recommended way to store compressed textures in files?

Tags: textures, assets, storage, compression

Uncompressed textures can be stored in lossy formats such as jpeg and it saves a lot of hard drive space. However for obvious reasons you cannot do the same on compressed textures.

So what is the recommended way to store compressed textures? Are there any lossy image compression that works even for any kind of compressed textures? If not, what kinds of lossless compression are usually used?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Perhaps the downvotes are due to "recommended way" sounding opinionated, and wanting to *compress compressed textures* sounds nonsensical at first read. I wish they'd left comments…

Answer (score 0):

For the various lossy block compressed formats like [DXT1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression) (aka BC1) you can apply standard lossless compression on top. The compression ratio will depend on the content of the textures, but I've seen it approximately halve the file size on a collection of various textures.

If you're really short on storage space you could store jpeg files on disc, and then convert to DXT1 at load time. However, that will probably slow down loading thanks to all the extra CPU work, and reduce texture quality.